# Exposed Kotlin. Problem with cyrillic encoding

Tags: kotlin, orm, collate, kotlin-exposed

I tryed to fix a problem with encodings. So, I sent from 'Postman', from web browser request to server, where I search data in database by keys in request. Request can be like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/books.getBooksByGenre/Документальное/0/10
```

(in browser).
Server receive string, like

```
http://localhost:8080/books.getBooksByGenre/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/0/10
```

then, takes params from url:
genreName: 'Документальное'
start: 0
count: 10.
Then, this data sends to dao:

```
override fun findGenreByName(genreName: String): DatabaseGenre {
    return transaction(db) { getGenreByName(genreName) }
}

private fun getGenreByName(genreName: String): DatabaseGenre {
    return try {
        val foundGenre = GenreEntity.find { Genres.genre eq genreName }.single()
        DatabaseGenre(foundGenre.id.value, foundGenre.genre, foundGenre.link)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw NothingFoundInDatabaseException("no one genre found by '$genreName'")
    } catch (e: NoSuchElementException) {
        val m = "Duplicates of genre with name '$genreName'"
        throw DuplicatedDataInDatabaseException(m)
    }
}
```

In log I see, that sql-query for finding genres is correct, but I receive an exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection is empty.
```

The sql-query, as I said, is correct:

```
SELECT genres.id, genres.genre, genres.link FROM genres WHERE genres.genre = 'Документальное'
```

Structure of genres table:

`genres
  id: int(10)
  genre: varchar(100)
  link: varchar(100`

I tryied, to select all genres, and this query executed almost correctly. So, I decided, to check this query with english word, and this query correctly executed:

```
SELECT genres.id, genres.genre, genres.link FROM genres WHERE genres.genre = 'simpleGenre'
```

I have not exceptions with this query.

So, what I've done wrong and how to fix problem with collations?

UPD:
As I said at github ([issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/433)), I've tryied this query it mysql cli and I receive correct answer.

Also, I've tryed to decode url params (with java URLDecoder class). It doesn't helps too.

Comment: Well, yeah. That's called URL encoding. If it doesn't automatically decode it, you'll need to do so manually.

Comment: @Zoe, thanks for your answer. But, why I saw in logs sql-query with cyrillic letters (in "normal" form)? It was without  encoded symbols, just normal cyrillic letters.

p.s. I'll try your advice and write here results

Comment: @Zoe, I've tryied your advice. It doesn't hepls. I updated my question description with my attempts to fix this problem and linkto github issue, where I wrote that from mysql cli all works fine

Comment: Do you have `characterEncoding=utf8` parameter in your MySQL connection URL? Like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?characterEncoding=utf8`. Another helpful parameter is `useUnicode=true`.

Comment: @madhead, fuu** ghm, it's really works. Thank you very mutch. Spent to this a week.
Don't know, how to mark this as correct answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks, @madhead. 
I tryied an advance of @madhead, and it works. So, from this time my DB connection URL looks like this:

```
val connect = Database.connect(
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database_name?characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true",
        driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        user = user_name,
        password = password
)
```

Comment: For me only works with `characterEncoding=UTF-8`